# Condition variable functions were not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, msdn, condition-variable

Its the first time I'm using WINAPI and with functions like **SleepConditionVariableCS** , **WakeConditionVariable** , **WaitForMultipleObjects** and **InitializeConditionVariable** Eclipse IDE told me that they were not declared in this scope.

All of them are supposedly included in the same lib **windows.h** so i dont know what's failings because other functions like *ExitThread* , *ReleaseSemaphore* and *WaitForSingleObject* are running without any problem.

It can be some problem with my c++ version? Or it exist any other library to include?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Windows 8 or newer?  According to MSDN, most of those functions were moved to Synchapi.h in Windows 8.

Comment: @MilesBudnek: This is not explicitly spelled out in the documentation, but you are still required to include *Windows.h* (not *WinBase.h* or *Synchapi.h*). And since those are part of the SDK (not the OS), it's not at all interesting, what OS the OP is using. What is interesting is the SDK version.

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for [SleepConditionVariableCS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686301.aspx) (or any other WIndows API call) tells you the minimum supported client and server OS. The API calls are conditionally declared, based on your target platform setting.

You can control your target platform by setting certain preprocessor macros (see [Using the Windows Headers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383745.aspx) for information). In your case you need to add

```
#define WINVER 0x0600
```

before including *Windows.h*, to target Windows Vista and later. It is common practice to define the preprocessor macro on the command line, to use a consistent environment across all compilation units.

Comment: suggest conditional overwriting WINVER